# Airflow Plugin - create own model and use airflow metadatabase for storing plugin specific data

Tags: python-3.x, plugins, sqlalchemy, airflow

I m trying to write a airflow plugin which adds a menu button, new view and an api endpoint. Additionally i need to read and store some data in a  database table which the plugin should create when airflow picks it up.

Problem exists when i have 2 files lets name them **view.py** and **mymodel.py**.
In view.py my whole views, menu buttons and so in is defined.

In mymodel.py just the sqlalchemy model (just the relevant lines and stripped table definition - see below)

**mymodel.py**:

```py
from airflow.models.base import Base

class someDataBase(Base):
    """
    Create Model someDataBase
    """

    print('create table someDataBaseTableName')

    __tablename__ = "someDataBaseTableName"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

In **view.py** i import the file:

```py
from someplugin.models.mymodel import someDataBase
```

folder structure:

```
├── plugins
│   └── someplugin
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── models
│       │   ├── mymodel.py
│       └── views
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── view.py
```

This throws the following error message:

*{{plugins_manager.py:146}} ERROR - Table 'someDataBaseTableName' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.*

(btw: extend_existing=True does not fix the problem :( )

I assume the problem is that airflow loads the plugin through the plugin_manager and the import statement loads the someDataBase class again. I think can confirm this behaviour if i add some logging in someDataBase class (lets name it 'mylogging' - see below).

```
airflow  | create table someDataBaseTableName
airflow  | create table someDataBaseTableName
```

Sort of a fix but not a satisfying one: If i define my someDataBase model directly in the view.py it works.

Any advice on how to fix this problem is very welcome. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table Already defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53486813/sqlalchemy-exc-invalidrequesterror-table-already-defined)

Answer (score 0):

I'm copying the answer I gave in [sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table Already defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53486813/sqlalchemy-exc-invalidrequesterror-table-already-defined/72831748#72831748) in case someone stumbles by this problem while using airflow.

> I had the same problem, and it turned out `models.py` was getting imported twice with different `__name__`.

> To debug it, place an

```
import sys
from pprint import pprint
pprint(list(sys.modules.keys())) # This line prints all imported modules
```

> in the relevant place and look for all `models` instances. In my case I had something like

```
[...,
 'models',
 ...,
 'package_name.models']
```

> So, in `package_name/models.py` I wrapped the whole file definition with

```
if __name__ != 'models':
    # original models.py code #
```

> and it solved the duplicated load.

> I think there is a more *pythonic* way of solving the problem, and it is has something to do with telling flask not to see `models.py` as a module or as a script (not sure which one is the correct one) in an `__init__.py` file somewhere, but even with all the reading done, I'm still quite confused on how these whole shenaningans work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Base class from *flask_appbuilder* package instead.

Replace `from airflow.models.base import Base` with `from flask_appbuilder import Base`.

It helped me to resolve that issue.